# Wilting and stunted growth of vegetables in NFT Hydroponics System

Tags: vegetables, diseases, pests, hydroponic, leaf-vegetables

My friends and I are starting a small scale hydroponics farm based in Jakarta, Indonesia. Recently we have experienced a problem in our system, mainly wilting, stunted growth, and yellowing leaves. The vegetables are spinach, Chinese mustard greens, bok choy, and sword lettuce (choy sam). We have listed the symptoms of each vegetable in the table below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

We are using an NFT system with a recirculated central water tank. Currently, we are investigating the cause of the problem in order to take efficient action to mitigate it. One of the possible causes is that we have tried using an eco enzyme as an organic pesticide. The enzyme is made through the fermentation of fruit peels and honey, so it might introduce pathogens to the system. We have tried to replace the nutrition water in the tank, but it doesn't seem to help much. Perhaps somebody can help us to determine the cause of the problem and perhaps give solutions that we can try to fix it.

Comment: Apart from stunted growth, are there deformities in the leaves, or perforations? Or odd patches or discolorations on the leaves?

Comment: hello, yes the leaves started to dry up and wilt, som of the shows other deformmities such as curling or burnt.

Comment: i have added some photos in the post so you can have a better picture of the deformities. thank you for replying!!